# Javascript - Fetch request happening after it supposed

Tags: javascript

I'm still new to javascript, I have this javascript problem from CS50 that is supposed to open a mailbox and clicking on an email is supposed to open the email. I think my on click part of the problem is right, but when I open my page and click  on an email it doesnt call the open_mail() function.
I've solved that the problem is that the load_mailbox function for being asynchronous is beign called after the DOM finishes to load, so technically theres no div with the class email-box when the DOM finishes to load, but i don't know how to solve this problem, can someone help please.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

// Use buttons to toggle between views
document.querySelector('#inbox').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('inbox'));
document.querySelector('#sent').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('sent'));
document.querySelector('#archived').addEventListener('click', () => load_mailbox('archive'));
document.querySelector('#compose').addEventListener('click', compose_email);
document.querySelector('#compose-form').addEventListener('submit', send_mail);
document.querySelectorAll('.email-box').forEach(function(box) {
  box.addEventListener('click', function (){
     open_mail();
   })
 });

// By default, load the inbox
load_mailbox('inbox');
});


function load_mailbox(mailbox) {

fetch(`/emails/${mailbox}`)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(emails => {
document.querySelector('#email-content').innerHTML = "";
emails.forEach(inbox_mail);
})
};

 function inbox_mail(email) {
 const element = document.createElement('div');
 if (document.querySelector(`#email-${email.id}`) === null) {

  element.id = (`email-${email.id}`);
  element.className = ("email-box");
  element.innerHTML = `<p>From ${email.sender}</p><p>${email.subject}</p><p>At ${email.timestamp} 
  </p>`;
    document.querySelector('#email-content').append(element);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I´d say the easiest solution would be to put the addEventListener to a point after the elements with class .email-box are created, e.g in your .then function after inbox_mail ran for each email

```
.then(emails => {
  document.querySelector('#email-content').innerHTML = "";
  emails.forEach(inbox_mail);

  document.querySelectorAll('.email-box').forEach(function(box) {
    box.addEventListener('click', function (){
      open_mail();
    });
  });

});
```

DOMContentLoaded will trigger when the DOM from the initial request/response was loaded. What you are doing in your fetch callback is called "DOM-Manipulation" as you create elements and append them to the DOM that has already been loaded.